# Chrome extension deployment

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have developed a chrome extension and i always use developer mode to debug. Now I want to deploy it. Is there a way to install extension per chrome profile? and I wonder how to get the extension id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1：extension ID can be found at chrome://extensions.like this：
[image]

2：I have no idea about your words "install extension per chrome profile". any way, if you want to use your chrome extension without developer mode. just use the"pack extension" button in the chrome extension page. you will get a crx file. to install it, just drag and drop it in you chrome.

you can also publish it to chorme web store. [see here](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/). then you and any other could easily install your extension frome chrome web store.

Comment: A friend wrote a service which generates the crx file for you ...
Quite handy
http://blog.tomtasche.at/2012/07/crxify.html

Comment: @DominicBartl No need to use an external site for creating the CRX. Just use `chrome.exe --pack-extension=path/to/extensionname` (optional: `--pack-extension-key=path/to/extensionname.pem`)

Comment: @DominicBartl http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html#preferences says the preference file should be name <Extension_ID>.json, but i cannot get the ID before I install it.

Comment: @RobW I know :P I also forgot to mention that crxify is for GitHub hosted projects :)

Comment: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html#preferences says in windows the folder where to put the preference file is c:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\6.0.422.0\Extensions\ but on Win7, this path does not exist.@DominicBartl

Comment: @HankYang Chrome can create many user profiles. I want to auto install my extension specific to one profile.

Comment: Now i have packaged my CRX file. but I want to auto-install it, not drag and drop.@HankYang

Comment: well，in win7 ,after some version, chrome is installed in C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application  by default. in the Google\Chrome\Application\CHROME_VERSION(which in my computer is 24.0.1312.57)\Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly to deploy your extension on web store you must have google developer account which costs $5.

Secondly the chrome extension id which you see while developing extension in your pc is different from what you will get when you have deployed your extension on chrome store.

Basically when you deploy your extension,chrome store ask you to upload the zip of your extension folder not the crx file.Also note that it will not give you any .pem file like you will get when you pack your extension locally.Chrome store will maintain the same extension id on each updation.

Note that you cannot update the extension with the same version.You must increment the version number on each updation,otherwise chrome will show error on updation.